# Copying files; two files have almost the same name, I want to copy the larger file

Tags: vb.net

I have a GUI application (VB.NET) the user will search for file in a predefined directory and copy it to a predefined destination. For each file the user will search for there are two files with ALMOST the same name but different file size. 80% of the time this is the case, and 20% only one file available.

For instance, there are two files "12345-A" and "12345-B". What I want is when the user searches by using "12345" only, the application will compare A and B and copy the larger size and if there is only A or B just copy what's available. A & B are not constant - could be any letters.

I am not sure how I should start, but I have designed the GUI simply with a textbox to enter the file name (to search) and textBox for the new name and Start Copy button. I am using:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile( 
  string to copy, 
  destination, 
  FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, 
  FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can I do some thing like search for files, file name contain "12345" and compare them and copy the larger file. if there are more than 2 files error message (search not valid), if there is one file matches then copy the file.

Comment: Use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(pattern) then with the resulting array of FileInfo order it for size, take the first

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the quick answer, that sounds exactly what I want, but I am new to programming, can you elaborate more on "resulting array of FileInfo order it for size, take the first "?

Comment: I would split your problem in 3 smaller ones. (1) Find the available files (2) Find the bigger file (3) Copy the file. If you do it in these steps, you might find your problem much easier, and easier to search for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to retrieve the files in the source folder that match the specified pattern. The resulting array of [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) objects can be ordered by the *Length* property in descending order and finally the first one could be used as the source file for the copy.

```
Dim di = new DirectoryInfo("your_source_directory_with_files")
Dim sourceFile = di.GetFiles("12345*.*").
                    OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Length).
                    FirstOrDefault()

if sourceFile IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim destFile = Path.Combine("your_destination_directory", sourceFile.Name)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(sourceFile.FullName, destFile,
                  FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, 
                  FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
End If
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, for some reason, I cant use var when I define sourcefile "Error Var is not declared" hence, I used Dim, then try to copy, it doesnt work as the sourcefile was defined as file info and not String to copy. any idea @steve ?

Comment: thanks for the correction, I actually found something shorter I removed all the IF .... etc and replaced it with Sourcefile.CopyTo("My destination")

Comment: Well I assumed you want to use CopyFile from the My namespace. It has options not available with CopyTo

Comment: Thats correct, with name space I can cancel the copy and see the progress dialog. Thanks a lot you solved my issue :)